# Gmail API doesn't recognize my attchments as attachments but as multipart/mixed why?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, multipart

My method of sending mail with attachments works, however, the API doesn't recognize my attachments as attachments but as multipart/mixed.
It's annoying because I need the id of my attachments for the rest of my application.

```
{
    "folder": [
        "SENT"
    ],
    "sender": "-----------",
    "recipientTo": [
        "---------"
    ],
    "recipientCc": [
        "---------"
    ],
    "recipientBcc": [
        ""
    ],
    "subject": "test attachment",
    "body": "Contenu du mail avec <strong>balise</strong> <span style='color:red;'>HTML</span> Morbi molestie mattis lobortis.<br> Donec blandit euismod eleifend. Aenean eleifend ullamcorper aliquam. Suspendisse aliquam gravida sapien, ut elementum elit. Quisque porttitor efficitur nunc tincidunt dignissim. Sed sollicitudin iaculis enim. Donec at purus quis leo lacinia aliquam.",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    **"contentType": "multipart/mixed",**
    "receivedDateTime": "2023-10-24T07:57:00.000+00:00",
    "read": true
}
```

I have the impression that I'm adding my attachments correctly.

```java
private MimeMessage createMimeMessageWithAttachments(final MailObjectRequestPayload mail) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    final List<MultipartFile> attachments = mail.getAttachment();

    // Create a new MimeMessage
    final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    final MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Set the email subject, content, and recipients
    mimeMessage.setSubject(mail.getSubject());

    final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    final MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent(mail.getBody(),"text/html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

    for (MultipartFile attachment : attachments) {

        final MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.getBytes(), attachment.getContentType());
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachmentPart.setFileName(attachment.getOriginalFilename());

        // add the file to the multipart
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
    }

    mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
    return mimeMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the whole thing in an "alternative" Part:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = ...;
MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

MimeBodyPart plain = new MimeBodyPart();
plain.setContent(..., "text/plain");
content.addBodyPart(plain);

MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
html.setContent(..., "text/html");
content.addBodyPart(html);

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.setFileName(...);
attachment.setDataHandler(...);
content.addBodyPart(attachment);

mimeMessage.setContent(content);
```

Comment: Using multipart/mixed should work though. The problem is more likely that the OP is not setting the disposition with `setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);`